# Call XPage script with http

Tags: rest, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to invoke an XPage from a rest client e.g http://myserver.com/myDB/myApp.nsf/mypage.xsp?attr=first

and have the XPage mypage.xsp to print the attr value.

```
var value1 = context.getUrlParameter("attr");
print(value1);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Google "XAgents", there are plenty of resources about how to call an XPage and return non-XPage code.

Also, make sure you set viewState property of the XPage to "nostate", because there's no point storing a component tree server-side for something that can't be partially refreshed.

Comment: Here's some boilerplate code to get you started: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xagent